# How to make textfield stick to its label in extjs?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, textfield

hi
i have a big windows with a form in it and some text fields.by default labels are aligned to the left and their input boxes are aligned to center. Is there a way to stick input boxes to their labels in left?
Is there any tutorial on how to work with css on extjs?

Comment: There are many ways to affect the placement of fields and their labels, but it would be much easier to help if you included your form code in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
labelAlign : 'right'
```

in your **form** config.
for example:

```
var form = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    height : 200,
    width  : 250,
    labelAlign : 'right'
    labelWidth : 80, //because my fieldlabel is short enough
    items      : [{
        fieldLabel : 'Name',
        ....
    }, ....]
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.it works when i create forms using new but when i use create form using xtypes,then labelAlign doesnt work:`{
                title:'Address',
                xtype:'form',
                defaults: {width: 230},
                defaultType: 'textfield',
                labelAlign: 'right',
                items: [{
                    fieldLabel: 'Address 1',
                    name: 'address1'
                }]}` i have to mention that this form is included in a card(wizard)layout.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your question on CSS: You won't be able to reposition Components contained in a Container with a FormLayout, unless you use `!important` all over the place.

This is because the layout sets the child components' dom `style` properties at render time.